# get a row from dynamic table (jquery)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a table using jquery
for some reason I cant get the specific row

I can use some help

jquery

```
$('table').on('click','tr:gt(0)',function(e){
    row=$(this).closest("tr");
    $('tr').css('background-color', '');
    row.css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

HTML

```
<table id="receivedFeeds" border="1">
<tr>
<th>Feed Address</th>
<th>Feed name</th>
<th>Received from</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

PHP

```
function addSendedFeedToUser(){// create a table of links and the user who send them
connectToDB();
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM send_feed WHERE user_receive='$username'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo '<tr>  <td>'.$row['feed_url'].'</td><td>'.$row['feed_name'].'</td> <td>'.$row['user_send'].'</td></tr>';
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this)` is enough don't use `.closest()` over that, since the selector itself is a row.

```
$('table').on('click','tr:gt(0)',function(e){
    row = $(this);
    $('tr').css('background-color', 'none');
    row.css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```